# Adaptative row in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have this figma layout to do:
[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWfyW.png)

I already have the chips layout done.
Those chips shows a list of strings.

But I don't know how to get that adaptative row, that when the string are to big, the line break and keep showing in another line.

Can you guys help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accompanist library has flow layouts that do exactly that: https://github.com/google/accompanist/tree/main/flowlayout

There are also similar flow layouts in the official [compose foundation library](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/4c9dacda7f47c2e04373e26d20998b8201536d43:compose/foundation/foundation-layout/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/FlowLayout.kt;l=52) that were just recently merged, but those are only available as [snapshot builds](https://androidx.dev/) for now.